# Windows Linux c++ compiling issue: "no matching function for call"

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, compiler-errors

I am working on a tool that provides a facility to write small c++ code within the framework it provides. The tool is windows and linux based. We write code into the windows. The compilation is done first on windows for testing purposes. Finally a linux build is performed to actually run the whole production tests on linux.

I created a function with following signature:

```
string myClass::myFunc(string& start, bool myflag, Class C1 & c1,
    long a=0, const char* b=NULL, void * c=NULL);
```

Now when the tool runs on windows (Microsoft visual express) everything works fine and all tests pass.

However when the code is compiled on linux I get an error stating that "no matching function for call".

Here is the function signature:

```
string myClass::myFunc(string& start, bool myflag, Class C1 & c1,
    long a=0, const char* b=NULL, void * c=NULL);
```

Error message:

```
myfile.cpp: no matching function for call to 
myClass::myFunc(std::string, bool, classC1&, long int&, 
const char *&, void*&) 

myfile.h: note: candidates are: 
std::string myClass:myFunc(std::string&, bool&, classC1&, 
long int, const char*, void*)
```

I do not have any access to the linux server. Hence cannot mention the linux distro or any other details.

Thanks in advance.

- ftp

Comment: Noticed that the myfile.h note has the bool as a reference.  Why is that?

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too. Maybe the tool generates the code differently in linux and windows. Unfortunately, I do not have the access to the linux machine. Hence can't be sure.

Comment: What you are doing is *not* "cross-compiling".  Just maintaining a portable codebase.

Comment: Agreed. removed the incorrect tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft's C++ compiler incorrectly allows binding non-`const` references to temporary variables.  They won't fix the bug now, because it would break existing code.  But that code already is broken on conformant compilers, as you've discovered.

See if you can't pass by value (for small types) or by const reference (for ones that are expensive to copy).  If it's an output argument, you'll need to change the caller to pass an lvalue instead of a temporary.

Comment: Hi Ben, which argument are you referring to ?

Comment: @user500949:  each of the arguments which disagree about a `&` suffix.

Comment: @user500949: Based on the error message, your first parameter is a temporary of type `std::string`, and doesn't match the non-const reference in the actual function.

Comment: BTW you don't need access to a linux computer to catch these errors.  A windows version of g++, like the cygwin one, should catch them just fine.

Comment: Hi Ben, saw my code and found that the first argument passed is indeed a temporary variable. So I need to change the function signature to string myClass::myFunc(const string& start, bool myflag, Class C1 & c1, long a=0, const char* b=NULL, void * c=NULL); ??? Btw, I do not have admin rights on my windows machine to install cygwin. Moreover this is a corporate laptop so can't install software without requisite permission.

Comment: @user500949: Wow.  I feel very sorry for you, trying to develop code without debugging permission.  Still, might be worth asking for g++, shouldn't be hard to justify because (1) it's free -- people who make you use express edition should like that, and (2) you're required to develop code to run on linux where g++ is used.  `clang` wouldn't be a bad option either.  But having two (or more) different compilers is the best way to catch portability problems early.

Comment: @user500949: And yes, adding `const` like that is the correct fix.  As long as nothing is actually trying to change the parameter (but then why wasn't it const already?)

Comment: Sure will try to get g++ installed. Well and not putting the const was me not programming the right way. Guess have a huge lot to learn :)

Comment: @BenVoigt just curious how did you guess that the problem was with the first argument? It could have been with any of the arguments.

Comment: @user500949: I checked the error message you gave and compared the two signatures.  I know that it's possible to drop `&`, or to add `const&`.  But adding just `&` is not allowed.

Comment: @BenVoigt sorry for my ignorance, however, i did not understand your previous statement.

Comment: For example, on the last argument, the error message shows that the caller has a `void*&`, and the function being called accepts `void*`.  That's fine, a copy of the pointer will be made.  But the first argument, the caller had a `std::string` (a temporary) and the function wanted a `std::string&`.

Comment: @BenVoigt thank you that helps. However would want to learn more about this. Could you point me to any relevant links ?